# How to align text in a clarity datagrid

Tags: css, angular, vmware-clarity

I have a angular app and i use clarity instead of bootstrap,

i have a datagrid and would like to know how you can align the header text of the datagrid to the center i have tried inline styling an css but doesn't seem to work.

code example 
html file

```
<clr-datagrid>
    <clr-dg-column class="align-content">User ID</clr-dg-column>
    <clr-dg-column class="align-content">Name</clr-dg-column>
    <clr-dg-column class="align-content">Creation date</clr-dg-column>
    <clr-dg-column class="align-content">Favorite color</clr-dg-column>

    <clr-dg-row >
        <clr-dg-cell>data</clr-dg-cell>
        <clr-dg-cell>data</clr-dg-cell>
        <clr-dg-cell>data</clr-dg-cell>
        <clr-dg-cell>data</clr-dg-cell>
    </clr-dg-row>
        <clr-dg-row >
        <clr-dg-cell>data</clr-dg-cell>
        <clr-dg-cell>data</clr-dg-cell>
        <clr-dg-cell>data</clr-dg-cell>
        <clr-dg-cell>data</clr-dg-cell>
    </clr-dg-row>
        <clr-dg-row >
        <clr-dg-cell>data</clr-dg-cell>
        <clr-dg-cell>data</clr-dg-cell>
        <clr-dg-cell>data</clr-dg-cell>
        <clr-dg-cell>data</clr-dg-cell>
    </clr-dg-row>

    <clr-dg-footer></clr-dg-footer>
</clr-datagrid>
```

css file

```
.align-content {
text-align: center;
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: We don't recommend centering text because it is harder to scan, which is why there isn't a built-in way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can target `datagrid-column-title` class and can give it style like:

```
.datagrid-column-title{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Also if you want the data rows to be centered as well at the same time, try this:

```
.datagrid-table .datagrid-cell{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Make sure you do these changes in `style.scss` of your application.

Here's a working demo:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tt3md6

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<clr-dg-cell class="clr-justify-content-center">
```

or

```
:host ::ng-deep {
  .datagrid-table .datagrid-column {
    justify-content: center;
  }
}
```

https://github.com/vmware/clarity/blob/3281f777e84b7efce3e7697e82f6c85df802b3b5/apps/website/data/angular-api.json#L1802